# What is the antonym to “legacy code”?

Tags: terminology, documentation, legacy-code

I am writing a software documentation and I need a antonym to "legacy code". Is there any established word for the antonym to "legacy code"? I'll need this antonym to describe that code which was written by myself.

Example: The main focus is to replace legacy code by [antonym] code.

Comment: I think that the term for the code you are writing today is *tomorrow's legacy code*.

Comment: Is your documentation for software which contains legacy code **and** your new written code?

Comment: "code with tests". Mike Feathers defines "legacy ode" as "code without tests", hence the antonym is "code with tests". Sadly, most developers write "legacy code" even in "green field" projects.

Comment: Since you ask for new code that replace existing code, Greenfield is not the right answer.
What you're asking is more likely **refactored code** as the result of performing a **refactoring** of the legacy code

Comment: @Walfrat: that depends on if the OP really wants to refactor, or to rewrite those parts from scratch.

Comment: @DocBrown this code would probably have to interract or be integrated with existing code, unless they really rewrite everything, which would be really surprising. Or  I have a definition too strict of Greenfield.

Comment: I think "new code" is all you need.

Comment: @Walfrat: sure, but to my understanding "refactoring" means applying code transformations like the [ones given by Fowler in his catalog](https://refactoring.com/catalog/). Throwing away even a single function and reimplementing it from scratch, even if the function has less than 10 lines and has the same signature than the old one, is not in that list.

Comment: @BernhardHiller: that was exactly the definition which came into my mind when I read the question. Lets hope for the OP he gets the hint ;-)

Comment: @DocBrown What about "Substitut algorithm" : You want to replace an algorithm with one that is clearer. Replace the body of the method with the new algorithm. PS : thanks for the link.

Comment: The word "legacy" always carries a negative connotation. I would suggest when writing the business case for replacing old code with new, that the reason the old code needs replaced is the focus and not the word legacy. Typical good reasons are lacking performance, scalability, supportability, and/or compatibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Greenfield**

A greenfield project is a project without any requirement of compatibility with legacy systems.  The allusion is to a field of green grass on which nothing has been built.

Comment: In such cases though, legacy projects are referred to as "brownfield" and not "legacy".

Comment: In OP case I diasagree `The main focus is to replace legacy code by [antonym] code.` There are already existing code, so this answer is not the right.

Comment: If the person is dealing with a system that contains legacy code, the replacement won't be "greenfield" since it still has to interface with other pre-existing code and infrastructure. The OP didn't give the impression that they are rewriting the entire code base.

Answer (score 3):

Going by your example sentence, I assume that you use *legacy code* in the sense of code that cannot be understood, maintained, or improved with reasonable effort, i.e., you hope that the code you wrote is not future legacy code. Therefore I suggest ***sustainable*** as the antonym, as it emphasises that future developers can use your code.

> The main focus is to replace legacy code by sustainable code.

Answer (score 2):

That would be just code or new code. Note that the term "legacy" in IT implies it is no longer considered optimal. Stuff you are not happy with yet still cannot do without. It may originally have been introduced as a respectful term or eufemism but its connotation today is rather negative.

A true antonym would imply you have no issues with the code regarding its applicability or usefulness to today's environment. You could call it modern code.

I would rather avoid qualifications like these at all though and stick to the technical qualifications instead that do not bear the old/bad versus new/good feel.

Comment: Or as I like to call it, "Legacy-code-in-waiting" or "Tomorrow's Legacy Code"

Answer (score -1):

In your example you can use "novel code".

Keep in mind that "legacy" is mostly a relative comparison between two bits of code, meaning "older than something" as there is no strict point at which code becomes "legacy". So a word like "novel", while not strictly in use for this, might be appropriate to strike the difference in reverse.

**[legacy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/legacy)**: *adj*
of or relating to old or outdated computer hardware, software, or data that, while still functional, does not work well with up-to-date systems.

**[novel](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/novel?s=t)**: *adj*
of a new kind; different from anything seen or known before.

Comment: I don't think "novel" is the right word here. It may not be "different from anything seen or known before", it may be just ordinary code, or code that is simply best-practice code to replace poorly written code. It won't be a new "kind" of code, just new code.

Comment: @Bryan  It is not about bad code versus good code, it is about code from the past versus code from the current era. From a linguistic point of view one could state that current is not an antonym to past, that it should imply future. Or at least "as new as it gets", the other end of the spectrum rather than the middle. So I do not think this is a bad answer at all.

Comment: _" It is not about bad code versus good code, it is about code from the past versus code from the current era"_ - I agree. "code from the current era" or even "code from the future"  is not necessarily novel. "novel" is not a synonym for "new". It's closer in meaning to "unique" or "ground-breaking". If I replace `a = a + 1` with `a += 1`, that's not novel because there are millions of lines of code that do similar things.

Comment: @BryanOakley `a+1` is a bad example, because it would not be legacy either, in itself. I would call the codebase novel, because it's a novel solution within the company, exactly unlike the previous legacy solution.